Keycloak Kafka - issue with Producer
I'm trying to implement Custom Event Listener in keycloak, I've managed to get the events that I was looking for and everything, but implementing Kafka is not going so well.
Just a heads up, I'm not the best at Java, so some concepts I might not know.
I've added to my pom.xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

The maven recognized it, it's listed under the dependencies

I've created a Producer class that I want to use on specific event:


When I drop the .jar file that I created while running 'mvn clean install' in Keycloaks event setting I get the:

KC-SERVICES0085: Failed to send type to it.aboutbits.CustomEventListenerProvider@3d0db5a6: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer
at it.aboutbits.Producer.publishEventToTopic(Producer.java:33)
at it.aboutbits.CustomEventListenerProvider.onEvent(CustomEventListenerProvider.java:40)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminEventBuilder.send(AdminEventBuilder.java:291)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminEventBuilder.success(AdminEventBuilder.java:273)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UserResource.deleteUser(UserResource.java:629)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UserResource$quarkusrestinvoker$deleteUser_1ab1e247046f32b48fb55de7f71f5540f6c8ea14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:115)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:65)
... 16 more

I've tried Googling this error quite a bit, but I haven't found anything...
I've modified this repo

My best guess is you have not added your kafka libraries to keycloak providers path. Can you share your docker file if you are using one ?

@Sithira, I'm not using docker for keycloak, it's run on my local machine

Oh i see! Have you added the required libraries to providers folder in keycloak ?

@Sithira, yeah I've sorted it with compiling a fat jar. Thanks for the hint that solved it at the end.

im glad you got it solved :-)

The issue is resolved by implementing a 'fat' jar.
I've compiled a jar file that has all dependencies in it, and it works.
